Facing Memory Leakage issues with SignalR / .NET 6 application
After hosting application on IIS or AKS linux pod when we made connection with specific SignalR hub then we noticed that it's memory get increased automatically after performing the same operation like facing user list .if we perform the same operation multiple times then we see every time memory get increased. After established the connection with signal hubs we also use Rebus for remaining communication.
private static BuiltinHandlerActivator _adapter = new BuiltinHandlerActivator();

private readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(RebusWeb<THub>));

public RebusWeb(IHubContext<THub> hub)
{
    try
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json");
        var config = configuration.Build();
        RebusConfigSettings.AppSettingsConfigure(config);
        _adapter.Register(() => new HubHandler<THub>(hub));
        var configurer = Configure.With(_adapter)
                 .Options(o =>
                 {
                     o.SetNumberOfWorkers(RebusConfigSettings.Workers);
                     o.RetryStrategy(maxDeliveryAttempts: RebusConfigSettings.RetryAttempts);
                 })
                .Logging(l => l.Log4Net())
                .Serialization(s => s.UseNewtonsoftJson(JsonInteroperabilityMode.PureJson))
                 .Routing(r =>
                 {
                     var routing = r.TypeBased();
                     var routers = config.GetSection("AppRouting").Get<List<AppRouting>>();
                     //routers.ForEach(sub => routing.Map(sub.Message.GetType(), sub.Endpoint));

                     foreach (var router in routers)
                     {
                         if (router.Message.Contains(","))
                         {
                             var message = Type.GetType(router.Message);
                             routing.Map(message, router.Endpoint);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             var assembly = Assembly.Load(router.Message);
                             var types = assembly.GetTypes();

                             foreach (var type in types)
                             {
                                 if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MessageModel)))
                                 {
                                     routing.Map(type, router.Endpoint);
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 })
                 .Events(x =>
                 {
                     x.BeforeMessageSent += (bus, headers, message, context) =>
                     {
                         if (RebusConfigSettings.TimeToBeReceived != "-1")
                         {
                             headers.Add(Headers.TimeToBeReceived, RebusConfigSettings.TimeToBeReceived);
                             headers.Add(Headers.Express, "rebus-express");
                         }
                     };
                 });

        string azureServiceBusUrl = EnvironmentVariablesManager.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureServiceBusUrl");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(azureServiceBusUrl))
        {
            var enableCompression = EnvironmentVariablesManager.GetEnvironmentVariable("EnableMessageCompression");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(enableCompression) && string.Compare(enableCompression, "true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                configurer = configurer.Options(o => o.EnableCompression(RebusConfigSettings.MessageCompressionSize));
            configurer.Transport(t => t.UseAzureServiceBus(azureServiceBusUrl, RebusConfigSettings.InputQueue).AutomaticallyRenewPeekLock()).Start();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex);
    }


For troubleshooting this kind of issue, we need analysis the memory noramlly to see which object inside the memory not release, currently from your codes, it seems there is no issue.

How many times is the RebusWeb constructor called?

@BrandoZhang,  yes true for singal hub i perform the same multiple time and create the dump file and try to understand the memory utilization part but could not properly figure out because few tool which i had use that shows "Managed Memory " utilization only 4 mb out of 65 mb .

@mookid8000 We have 22 hubs so constructor will get called 22 times and all hubs hosted on the same linux pod and initially it will start to take 1.20GB memory when very first connection get established for all hubs and when we play some functionality then we observed it get's increased and less then 2hours memory will reach to 2GB. and when we hosted on iis we have observed when we performsame operation like fetching user list again and again so with singal hub memory get increased from 30mb to 65mb in few minutes and if wait for few minutes then memory get decreas only few mb like 2-5mb

It's not readily possible for me to figure out what could cause a memory leak. I agree with @BrandoZhang that it would be very helpful with a memory profiler diff that shows which types of objects are building up.

I suggest you could try to use the debug analysis to see which object is increasing.
